# State of TwinCAT events is not correct in the HMI and Visual Studio Logged Events

Tags: twincat

We use the TwinCAT 3 [Event Logger](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_eventlogger/4278559115.html?id=4498649442738105815) to track events in our machine. The events are shown to the user with the [Event grid control](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/te2000_tc3_hmi_engineering/5239612555.html&id=).

Alarms which are raised shows up correctly in the event grid. Every so often it happens that an alarm is cleared, but it never updates in the grid control as cleared. Also when we check the alarm in Visual Studio with the Logged Events window, it doesn't have a cleared date. However, when we check the state of the `FB_TcAlarm` it has a cleared date or the `eConfirmationState` is set as `NotRequired` which means the alarm is currently not in the raised state.

The weird thing is that this doesn't always happen--most of the time the alarms work correctly. Only in rare cases they don't work. Also it is not always the same alarms which malfunction.

Anyone else if suffering from this? Or any idea how to solve/reproduce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have disappeared after we updated to HMI v1.12 and TwinCAT version 4024.10 I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I have kind of the same problem, but for me it happens when I change something in the code (I have a dynamic array of TcCom objects and FB_Alarms get their own index and register to those TcCom objects with their own name and message) and if I change the name (which is used for doublechecking index) or reset to origin, the old indexes are reset and the old alarms cannot be confirmed away since the original recipient is no longer there. At this point I have to clear logged events through XAE to PLC, stop HMI and delete 2 files in the server.

I know this is not a complete answer, but it helps to know that the HMI has its own eventLogger instance with its own record, PLC has it's own too, and one possible reason for unresponsive alarms is that the recipient FB_TcAlarm has been changed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Which files do you remove?

Comment: The filenames are logger.db and logger.db-journal in HMI Server folders (in Windows CE, Hard Disk\Twincat\Functions\TF2000-HMI-Server\l, in PC it’s somewhere inside Twincat folder). The PLC has it’s own files too, I think they are the same name or almost. When HMI files are deleted it will try to inport event history from PLC so both need to be removed. You can also clear the eventlog from (PLC only) through XAE, see this https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_eventlogger/27021602616987915.html&id= )